# Why Hindu Person hand tied with Muslim holy thread?

Tags: belief, other-religions

i have one hindu friend, he tied with holy thread on his wrist i asked him what about thread, he replied: this thread belongs to Muslim Religion.  & it look like this: [image],

Comment: Speculating about why a particular person would wear a thread that he himself called a Muslim thread has nothing to do with Hinduism, so I'm closing your question.

Comment: I don't think it has to do anything with the religion, but Its might be due to the secular nature of hindus of considering all religion taking you to the same supreme being.